# presto - moving worker from docker to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, presto

I have a minimal (working) **presto** installation (one coordinator and a worker on the same host) that I want to expand. I've created a container with a worker node and it works when deployed via docker (IE shows up in presto CLI).

> select * from system.runtime.nodes;

When I move said container my k8 cluster and create a few pods it seems that the pods can contact the coordinator but they never show up in the CLI. The logs for the pods show that they have discovered the coordinator and there aren't any error msgs in the coordinator logs so Im puzzled as to where the disconnect is.

#### deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: presto-worker
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: presto-worker
  replicas: 2 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: presto-worker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: presto-image
        image: docker.io/mystuff/presto-image:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: Your configuration is unclear: 1. Have you created a service? If yes - could you provide yaml file to see your service configuration? 2. Could you please provide logs that you have. 3. After reading your question, I understood that your coordinator host is outside of the cluster where your created worker nodes and you haven’t created service/ingress to expose worker nodes to a coordinator. That's why it is not visible from the cluster.

Comment: My understanding of a service is that it exposes one worker at a time. Is this incorrect? A load balancer of sorts.

Comment: it would be better to share more logs or use `com.facebook.presto=DEBUG` in `log.properties` to get more feedback to tell where things go wrong (so far I didn't know whether it's your presto configuration or presto cluster setup)

Comment: Have you seen the k8s tempaltes for presto cluster from this repo? https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/presto/templates

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've combined parts of a Deployment and a Service; they're two different objects.  You can break this up:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: presto-worker
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: presto-worker
  replicas: 2 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: presto-worker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: presto-image
        image: docker.io/mystuff/presto-image:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: presto-worker
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: presto-worker
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
```

The Service selector points at specific pods; it needs to match the deployment spec's pod template labels.  The Deployment selector names the pods that the Deployment manages.  In both cases they point at pods but they're for different purposes.

Comment: Will this permit access to all pods simultaneously? My understanding of a service (in this context) was this it offered load balancing (of a sort). These pods are supposed to be part of a cluster.

Comment: Have you tried reconfigure using @david-maze approach? Share your current configuration and logs. You need NodePort service in your case. Read about NodePort [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). NodePort: Exposes the service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP service, to which the NodePort service will route, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the NodePort service, from outside the cluster, by requesting <NodeIP>:<NodePort>.

Comment: I tried same, but its give disabling glue catalog and then from running crashes

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working Helm chart (i.e., template package of k8s resources) for presto: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/presto.

Here's basic design of a presto cluster in k8s from above Chart:

1. single coordinator. discoverable (by workers) over http://:8080 - this is where you need a k8s service exposed for coordinator so that all workers can perform discovery against this coordinator (actually it's the discover service exposed by coordinator).
2. a number of stateless workers via a k8s deployment. You do not need to expose any ports nor k8s service since no external process will reach to worker process at all.
3. uses k8s configMap to inject customized presto configuration. the most important config for a presto cluster is `discovery-server.enabled=true` in `<presto-home>/etc/config.properties` of your presto coordinator or your coordinator is not discoverable at all. (a.k.a., can not have external worker process over network).

According to this question, you need to make sure presto coordinator is accessible by worker process via DNS name like `http://my-presto-coordinator:8080`.

---

This is what I got from chart `stable/presto` by running `helm template .` (render all template in stdout). you will need to replace `RELEASE-NAME` with lowercase strings to use it:

```
---
# Source: charts/presto/templates/deployment-worker.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-presto-worker
  labels:
    app: presto
    chart: presto-0.1
    release: RELEASE-NAME
    heritage: Tiller
    component: worker
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: presto
      release: RELEASE-NAME
      component: worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: presto
        release: RELEASE-NAME
        component: worker
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: RELEASE-NAME-presto-worker
      containers:
        - name: presto-worker
          image: "bivas/presto:0.196"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["/bin/bash"]
          args:
            - /etc/presto/docker-presto.sh
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/presto
              name: config-volume
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - /etc/presto/health_check.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 25
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - /etc/presto/health_check.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          resources:
            {}
```